# Elastic search not sorting correctly

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a Elastic search mapping as below. The filed amount is of type keyword

```
{
   "claims-service":{
      "mappings":{
         "properties":{
            "requestedAmount":{
               "properties":{
                  "amount":{
                     "type":"keyword"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

But when i try to sort it using the below mentioned query, it's not sorting the ascending order.

```
GET /claims-service/_search
{
  "size": 770,
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "requestedAmount.amount": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The result i'm getting is like below. As you see clearly i'm trying to sort it in ascending order, but its giving me the wrong result.

```
{
        "_index" : "claims-service",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "79600",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : "79600",
          "requestedAmount" : {
            "amount" : "101402.310000"
          }
        },
        "sort" : [
          "101402.310000"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "claims-service",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "76800",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : "76800",
          
          "requestedAmount" : {
            "amount" : "104.160000"
          },
         
        "sort" : [
          "104.160000"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : claims-service",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "72750",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : "72750",
         
          "requestedAmount" : {
            "amount" : "104.391000"
          },
          
        "sort" : [
          "104.391000"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "claims-service",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "79900",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : "79900",
         
        
        },
        "sort" : [
          "104909.340000"
        ]
      }
```

As you can make out by looking into sort field, the values are actually displayed as `["101402.310000", "104.391000",  "104909.340000"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Being of type `keyword`, the `amount` field is sorted in lexicographical order (i.e. alphabetic order), which is consistent with what you're seeing.

If you want to sort in numerical order, you need to use a [numeric data type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/number.html), such as `double` for instance. You can keep your `keyword` field and add a sub-field of type `double`. After changing the mapping in that

```
PUT claims-service/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "requestedAmount": {
      "properties": {
        "amount": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "fields": {
            "numeric": {
              "type": "double"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After changing your mapping with the above command, you can run the next
command in order to index the `amount.numeric` sub-field

```
POST claims-service/_update_by_query
```

You'll then be able to use that new field for properly sorting the data.

```
"sort": [
  {
    "requestedAmount.amount.numeric": {
      "order": "asc"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Ooh ok. Thank you Val. Can i make this as multifield and mark main field as Text and inner field as double?

Comment: Hi Val, the sorting is not working properly for double data types.When I have values ex: 13.0, 2.0, 5.0, 9.0. The sort is giving me the result as 9.0,5.0, 2.0, 13.0. It is putting 13.0 at the last.