# Sorting in Elasticsearch make consistency problem

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm sending my data to elasticsearch with index_number of documents. Its unique identifier. When i try to sort it with this, from python client i get this consistency problem as you see in the picture.

[image: index_number]

This is my query dsl

```
"size": 1,
"query": {
    "match_all": {}
},
"sort": [
    {
        "index_number.keyword": {
            "order": "asc",
            "missing": "_last",
            "unmapped_type": "String"
        }
    }
]
```

In logstash output

```
output{
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        index => "logstash_%{+yyyy-MM-dd}"
        manage_template => true
        template_name => "logstash_template"
        template => "..../logstash_template.json"
        http_compression => true
    }
}

In my logstash template.json
...

{
"index_patterns": ["logstash_*"],
"template": {
  "settings":{
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "number_of_replicas": 0,
    "index": {
      "sort.field": "index_number", 
      "sort.order": "asc"  
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic_templates":{
      "string_fields": {
        "match": "*",
        "match_mapping_type": "string",
        "mapping": {"type":"keyword"}
      }
    },
    "properties": {
      "index_number": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "fields": {
          "numeric": {
            "type": "double"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
  }

....
```

Mapping on elasticsearch

```
{
  "logstash_2020-03-12" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        .....
        "index_number" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "city" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "country" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        -----
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can i solve it? Thanks for answering.

Comment: What do you mean by "concurrency problem"?

Comment: As seen on the picture, I ve used sorting via asc. But the result showing that "13109" > "131089".

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65663222/elastic-search-not-sorting-correctly/65663348#65663348 (hint: you need a numeric type in order to sort numerically and not alphabetically)

Comment: sorry for my bad english I mean consistency

Comment: I have tried this in logstash on elasticsearch template but it still gives me same issue

Comment: I have edited question with logstash template

Comment: After reindexing all of your data, you need to sort on `index_number.numeric`

Comment: "index_number.numeric": {
                "order": "asc",
                "missing": "_last",
            }

Comment: I have tried with this

Comment: RequestError(400, u'search_phase_execution_exception', u'No mapping found for [index_number.numeric] in order to sort on')

Comment: I have got this error. But logstash says it include template

Comment: That means you haven't modified the mapping of your index and reindexed your data. Changing the index template in Logstash will not recreate your index (it already exists). You need to modify the index mapping directly. Please follow the post I've linked to

Comment: [2021-01-11T19:17:46,025][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Attempting to install template {:manage_template=...

Comment: Please read my comments again. Changing the template will not change your existing index. The template will only kick in when the next index will be created

Comment: But before changing template that I ve already deleted all indices on elasticsearch nodes

Comment: Also I m so thankfull you are answering

Comment: If you've deleted all your indexes, modified the index template and restarted Logstash to reinstall the new template, then the newly created indexes should have the right mapping and the query should work... Can you get the mapping of the newly created index?

Comment: Logstash says its installed template but when i check from dev tools, I see its text field. I dont know why

Comment: Maybe your template doesn't match the index you're creating. Can you share your full template and Logstash configuration?

Comment: I have edited question with logstash output and template @Val

Comment: Thanks, now add the mapping you get when running `GET logstash_*`, i.e. the real mapping of your index(es)

Comment: I have edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add [`template_overwrite`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-template_overwrite) to your Logstash output configuration otherwise the `logstash_template` is not overridden if it already exists:

```
output{
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        index => "logstash_%{+yyyy-MM-dd}"
        manage_template => true
        template_override => true                         <-- add this
        template_name => "logstash_template"
        template => "..../logstash_template.json"
        http_compression => true
    }
}
```

Make sure that your `logstash_template.json` file has the following format:

```
{
  "index_patterns": [
    "logstash_*"
  ],
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "number_of_replicas": 0,
    "index": {
      "sort.field": "index_number",
      "sort.order": "asc"
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic_templates": {
      "string_fields": {
        "match": "*",
        "match_mapping_type": "string",
        "mapping": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    },
    "properties": {
      "index_number": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "fields": {
          "numeric": {
            "type": "double"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You had `mappings` and `settings` enclosed within the `template` section, but this is only for the new [index templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-templates.html) which the `elasticsearch` Logstash output doesn't support yet. You need to use the [legacy index templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates-v1.html).

Comment: I have got this error Unknown setting 'template_override' for elasticsearch

Comment: Which version of Logstash are you using?

Comment: I ve also tried to update elasticsearch output plugin. But not worked 'template_override' again

Comment: hahah funy thing that i didnt see. Not template override , it has to be "template_overwrite" :D

Comment: Yes, as I wrote in my answer with an underscore :-)

Comment: When i tried to fetch with python rest client it gives returns true value. But when i check mapping on devtools, it still says "text" is it normal?

Comment: Did you manage to make it work? Does the index have the right mapping now?

Comment: When i run this code on devtools => GET /logstash_*/_mapping , I see the field is "text" but when i fetch from python rest client i see index_numbers ordered

Comment: Nope sorry again same issue from python rest too

Comment: Can you compare `logstash_template.json` with what you get from `GET _template/logstash_template` in Dev Tools? Are they identical?

Comment: No, in logstash_template its integer, but in devtools it says it text

Comment: Something's wrong somewhere, but at this point, it's really hard to say without being able to dive into it.

Comment: What do you see when running `GET _template/logstash_template`?

Comment: {
  "logstash_template" : {
    "order" : 0,
    "index_patterns" : [
      "logstash_*"
    ],
    "settings" : { },
    "mappings" : { },
    "aliases" : { }
  }
}

Comment: Are settings and mappings really empty? Ohhhh I know why!! Updating my answer